# How can I find the difference between two images of different shape/size in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-size, image-comparison

I am stuck at the situation where i have to find difference between the images of slight different shapes which I am unable to do.

I have tried to resize the image using cv2, but after making the images' size similar, the amount of differences are quite large after doing comparison.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75309853/edit) your question and provide a definition of "difference" and "slight different shapes". Also provide an example of the two images to be compared. If they are binary images, please provide binary PNG images.

Comment: Yes, please add your images and your current code! [ask]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).